# Template parameter shadows with friend?

Tags: c++, templates

In the following example which overloads `<< operator`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class MyClass {

    public:
        MyClass(T X, T Y):x(X), y(Y) {}

        template <typename U>
        friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, const MyClass<U> &cl);

    private:
        T x;
        T y;
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, const MyClass<T> &cl)
{
    os << cl.x << " " << cl.y;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass<int> cl(1, 2);
    std::cout << cl << std::endl;
}
```

I have searched other questions but I couldn't find why exactly do I need:

```
template <typename U>
friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, const MyClass<U> &cl);
```

the `U` instead of `T` in the `typename`? Because in the end `U` and `T` are both `ints`.

Comment: Is there a question in there?! The clearer and more concise your question, the higher your chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: Yes, the question is why exactly do I need the `U` instead of `T` in the `typename`? Why doesn't it work without `U`?

Comment: Don't tell me; write it in the question.

Comment: @yzt: Don't you already see it? Need a [screenshot](http://i61.tinypic.com/25q6gyh.png)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `template <typename T>` again because, on the rest of the line, it wouldn't know which of the two `T`s you mean. It's kind of like this, which is also an error:

```
void foo(int x) {
  int x = 4;
  cout << x;  // which x?
}
```

The compiler is not smart enough to figure out that in this case you will always want the two `T`s to be the same, much like the error in the `foo` function above would not go away if you only ever called `foo(4)` in your program.

But what you've realized here is that you don't actually need the template arguments for `operator<<` at all here! That's because in this context you know exactly what type you want to use, whch is `MyClass<T>`. Normally, you can get rid of template parameters when you know the exact types you want. This is called an *explicit specialization*, and would normally look something like this:

```
template <>
friend std::ostream& operator<< <T>(std::ostream& os, const MyClass<T> &cl);
```

Note the empty template argument list `template <>`, which says "I don't need template arguments" and then the `<T>` after the function name, which says, "because I want the template argument type to be exactly `T`", where `T` is already known within a particular instantiation of the `MyClass` template. However this **does not work** here, because there is simply a rule in the C++ language specification that explicit specializations aren't allowed in `friend` declarations. (I am not exactly sure what the rationale is behind this rule, but it's a rule.)

So since you can't re-use the identifier `T`, and you can't explicitly specialize, the only option remaining is to use some *other* identifier, like `U`, for the template parameter.